# Python Freeing Up Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using Threads from the threading class for the first time and they don't seem to be freeing themselves up after the function runs. I am attempting to have a max of 5 threads running at once. Since one thread creates the next there will be some overlap but I'm seeing 2000+ threads running at once before I get the exception "can't start new thread".

```
from threading import Thread
import string

URLS = ['LONG LIST OF URLS HERE']

currentThread = 0
LASTTHREAD = len(URLS) - 1
MAXTHREADS = 5
threads = [None] * (LASTTHREAD + 1)

def getURL(threadName, currentThread):
  print('Thread Name = ' + threadName)
  print('URL = ' + str(URLS[currentThread]))
  if currentThread < LASTTHREAD:
    currentThread = currentThread + 1
    thisThread = currentThread
    try:
      threads[thisThread] = Thread(target = getURL, args = ('thread' + str(thisThread), currentThread, ))
      threads[thisThread].start()
      threads[thisThread].join()
    except Exception,e:
      print "Error: unable to start thread"
      print str(e)

for i in range(0, MAXTHREADS):
  currentThread = currentThread + 1
  try:
    threads[i] = Thread(target = getURL, args = ('thread' + str(i), currentThread, ))
    threads[i].start()
    threads[i].join()
  except Exception,e:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"
    print str(e)
```

I'm open to any other cleaning up I can do here as well since I'm pretty new to python and entirely new to threading. I'm just trying to get the threading set up properly at this point. Eventually this will scrape the URLS.

Comment: Having your spawned threads spawn threads themselves is rather unusual. I'd suggest at the minimum refactoring so that your master thread does all the spawning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into a thread pool, and having the threads take tasks from a suitable shared data structure (e.g. a queue) rather than starting new threads all the time.

Depending on what it is you actually want to do, if you're using CPython (if you don't know what I mean by CPython, you will be) you might not actually get any performance improvement from using threads (due to global interpreter lock). So you might be better off looking into the multiprocessing module.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

def do_work(url):
  print "Processing URL:" + url 

q = Queue()
for i in range(5):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in ['url_' + str(i) for i in range(2000)]:
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: See example in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html (right at the bottom)